# SQL aggregation based on time and column change

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Have a situation where I'm trying to calculate start, end time and time spent in different areas in a location.

I have the data with timestamp and the location of the person when captured by the system.

The normal case is when a location change and in that case, the end time should be the previous seen value. The exception is when a person is not seen for 5m or more, in which case the endTime shall be the last seen (see above the line 2 and 3 of the aggregation output required).

Original data

```
date, zone
8h10m, room1
8h12m, room1
8h15m, hall
8h16m, hall
8h25m, hall
8h29m, hall
8h30m, room2
8h34m, room2
8h38m, room2
8h42m, room2
```

Aggregation/Summary required in the following way (or similar):

```
startDate, endDate, time, zone
8h10m, 8h12m, 3m, room1
8h15m, 8h16m, 2m, hall   <-- special case time >5m
8h25m, 8h29m, 5m, hall
8h30, 8h42m, 9n, room2
```

Can you give me an idea of how can I make such "aggregation/summary" in SQL? I'm using BigQuery, but I believe standard SQL should do the job.

Thanks,

Rui

Comment: what the data type of field `date`? is it really string as it is in sample data in your question? or it is datetime or timestamp as it ideally should be?

Comment: The last line states: 8h30, 8h42m, 9n, room2  ---> 13m ?

Comment: yes Samuel, 13m ... my mistake ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  min(date) as startDate, max(date) as endDate, 
  time_diff(max(date), min(date), minute) + 1 as time, zone
from (
  select *, countif(new_zone) over (partition by zone order by date) as zone_number
  from (
    select *, 
      ifnull(date - lag(date) over (partition by zone order by date) > make_interval(minute => 5)
        or zone != lag(zone) over(order by date), true) as new_zone
    from your_table
  )
)
group by zone, zone_number
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select time "8:10:00" as date, "room1" as zone union all 
  select "8:12:00", "room1" union all 
  select "8:15:00", "hall" union all 
  select "8:16:00", "hall" union all 
  select "8:25:00", "hall" union all 
  select "8:29:00", "hall" union all 
  select "8:30:00", "room2" union all 
  select "8:34:00", "room2" union all 
  select "8:38:00", "room2" union all 
  select "8:42:00", "room2"
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Very good and short query for that task. If the person enters the same zone again within 5 minutes, it will not be shown. When  the person goes at 9:43 to the hall and then back to room2 at 9:44, the 2nd hall will be shown, but not the 2nd room2.

Comment: thx! @Samuel - you are right - fixed :o)

Comment: Many thanks! working as expected ... just had to change from time_diff to date_diff since I'm using TIMESTAMP type field in BigQuery.
still trying to understand the logic, but I will get there ;-)
Thanks once again,
Rui

Answer (score 1):

From Mikhail Berlyant solution, the concept with `countif` has been used to simplify this query. This answer is capable of identifing every move, also if the person re-eneters a room withhin 5 minutes. See addition data provided in the table.

There are several step needed:

- add lines with zones `---` when 5 minutes no data is there: Set `over_5:minutes` true when difference from previous line (`lag`) to current line is over 5 minutes. `unnest([0,1]) as x` to duplicate dataset and `qualify` to include dataset in this case.
- sort all of the following statements by the column `date, x` in the `over(order by date, x)`
- with `lag` obtain the last room and the last date. Because of the unnest x, look two rows back.
- compare the last room to the current one, if they differ, set the `zone_change` to true.
- `countif(zone_change)` from 1st to current date to obtain the `zone_id`.  This curresponds to a single zone.
- To this `zone_id` count the time the `x` was 0; this is the case when 5 minutes no position was given.
- `group by zone_id` and calculate the  min and max date
- remove the `---` zones by  filtering

```
With tbl as
(
SELECT TIME "8:10:00" as date, "room1" as zone
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:12:00", "room1"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:15:00", "hall"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:16:00", "hall"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:25:00", "hall"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:29:00", "hall"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:30:00", "room2"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:34:00", "room2"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:38:00", "room2"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:42:00", "room2"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:43:00", "hall"
UNION ALL SELECT TIME "8:44:00", "room2"
)

SELECT 
zone_id,
zone,
min(date) as startDate,
max(date) as endDate,
time_diff(max(date),min(date),minute)+1 as time_minutes
FROM
(
SELECT *,
countif(x=0)  over (ORDER BY date,x RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)+
countif(zone_change) over (ORDER BY date,x RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as zone_id
FROM
(
SELECT date,x,if(x=1,zone,"---") as zone,
time_diff(date,lag(date,2) over (order by date),minute)>5 as over_5_minutes,
zone!=lag(zone,2) over (order by date,x) as zone_change
FROM tbl, unnest([0,1]) as x
Qualify over_5_minutes or x=1
)
)
where zone!="---"
group by 1,2
order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Samuel!
I will try your solution as well. Good to have solutions to choose from.
Appreciate your support.
Rui